# Copy from Mac to ZFS SMB share hangs the copy process once ARC_Max reached

Tags: samba, mac, zfs

New installation of 20.04.2 and ZFS installed via Cockpit. I've setup SMB shares and have managed to get TimeMachine working.

The problem is when I want to copy/paste while on the Mac (Big Sur) to an SMB share on the ZFS volume. Anything under 16GB is great. The network hits 2.3Gb (2.5Gb cards), all great. Anything over 16.x GB in size and the copy process just hangs once it's transferred about 17GB. No obvious errors. From the Mac it just shows as copying, the transferred amount doesn't change and neither does the time remaining.

If I try to stop the copy process from the Mac, the process just hangs i.e. says stopping but doesn't. I can't unmount the share on the Mac (process is using the device). When I shutdown the Mac, it won't shutdown cleanly and hangs. Ultimately it does shutdown but then reports the system had an issue shutting down when it reboots.

I don't know if it's a red herring but that size is the same as that allocated to Arc_Max. The system has 32GB installed but it looks like this value is set to 50% of the installed amount. This is the only job the ubuntu machine is performing so I'm happy to increase the value but not sure if it will just delay the problem. (Hell...I'll go and try it and see)

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Nope...increasing arc_max to 28GB didn't make any difference. Still hangs at 17.54GB of 100.25GB transferred.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Arc_Max, in fact I don't think it has anything to do with ZFS. I can copy the same files from a PC to the ZFS volume without a problem. I think this is more a an OSX/SMB issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with ZFS and appears all SMB related with Mac OSX. I understand this is not uncommon...

Using AFP to the same folder works. I'll need to review the SMB setting.